# Function stops working

Tags: functions, ajax, database

I have a function which inserts certain values to the database on publish_post but for some reason when I add more to the code it all of a sudden stops working. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong please or what is wrong with the code that makes it stop working....

Here is the code when it is working:

```
$message = '<div class="notification-user-image" style="background-image: url('. $user_avatar .');"></div> <strong>' .  $user_company_name . '</strong> posted a new ad <strong>' . substr($post_title, 0, 12).'...' . '</strong>';
```

and here it is when it stops working:

```
$message = '<div class="notification-user-image" style="background-image: url('. $user_avatar .');"></div> <strong>' .  $user_company_name . '</strong> posted a new ad <strong>' . substr($post_title, 0, 12).'...' . '</strong>'.'<div class="notification-time"><abbr class="timeago" title="' . $creation_date_time . '"></abbr></div>';
```

Comment: Hard to tell from your posted code. What are the values of the variables inside the divs?  Are there any error messages on the screen, or in the error.log file? Any messages from the Developer's console? What does the generated code look like (which would show the values of the strings)?

Comment: ...and I expect that there is some issue with $creation_date_time variable. Which you will find out if you look at the error logs, or the generated page content (if no fatal errors).

Comment: It may also be worth checking if you are exceeding a character limit/field size in your database if this message variable is posted directly to a field in the database.

Comment: @AnsonWHan I suspect that might be the issue....but no matter, I figured out a way around it and it's working now. Thanks for the advice! :)